# How to check two conditions in filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array,

```
const array = [
{
   name: G1,
   male: true,
   female: false
},
{
   name: G2,
   male: false,
   female: true
}]
```

Now in this, i need to filter or fetch name=G1, and then i need to check if male is true or female is true ? And the output as Male or Female ?

I tried ;

```
array.filter(e => e.name === "G1" && (e.malesSeat === true || e.ladiesSeat === true))
```

This gives, result but how to know which is true as Male or Female ?

Expected Result:

```
Male === true or just Male
```

As for G1, only Male is true!

Comment: do want only one object as result? please add the wanted result. btw, your properties are booleans not strings.

Comment: check now @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

You are using `===` and it means that both operands should be the same type. However `female` or `male` keys have boolean values. So we should have the boolean values in conditions:

```
array.filter(e => e.name === "G1" && (e.male === true || e.female === true))
```

or just use `==`

```
array.filter(e => e.name === "G1" && (e.male == 'true' || e.female == 'true'))
```

**UPDATE:**

As you just want to filter and decide whether its `male` of `female`, then we can use `filter` with `map` methods:

```
let result = array.filter(e => e.name === "G1")
    .map(s=> s.male ? 'Male' : 'Female');
```

An example:

```js
const array = [
    {
       name: 'G1',
       male: true,
       female: false
    },
    {
       name: 'G2',
       male: false,
       female: true
    }]

    
let result = array.filter(e => e.name === "G1")
.map(s=> s.male ? 'Male' : 'Female');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Jenifer_009 please, see my updated answer

Comment: I dont need full object just need if its Male, then Male as output or if its female then Female as output !

Comment: @Jenifer_009 please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the code. Just use male or female.

```js
const array = [
{
   name: 'G1',
   male: true,
   female: false
},
{
   name: 'G2',
   male: false,
   female: true
}]

const arr = array.filter(e => e.name === "G1" && (e.male || e.female))
   console.log(arr.length >= 1 ? (arr[0].male ? 'Male' : 'Female') : 'Not found')
```

Comment: I dont need full object just need if its Male, then Male as output or if its female then Female as output !

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and check the properties.

This approach takes [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with a condition which takes only the boolena properties directly without a superfluous check of being `true` or `false`.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: 'G1', male: true, female: false }, { name: 'G2', male: false, female: true }],
    item = array.find(e => e.name === "G1" && (e.male || e.female)) || {};

console.log(item.male ? 'Male' : item.female ? 'Female' : 'X');
```

Comment: How, can it be handled, when there is only single object in a array ? it gives undefined !

Comment: just add `|| {}` behind `find`. it takes a default object and the later checks returns an `'X'`.